# Reflexive Verbs for Emphasis

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-order, conjunction, reflexive

Recently I encountered 2 versions of a Steve Jobs' quote in German and would like to ask some questions about them.

The quotes are:

> Ihre Zeit ist begrenzt, also verschwenden Sie sie nicht damit, das Leben eines anderen zu leben.

and

> Eure Zeit ist begrenzt. Vergeudet sie nicht damit, das Leben eines anderen zu leben.

For the first quote:

1: Is "sich verschwenden" used for emphasis? Would simply "verschwenden" work here?

2: why is "damit" used with "also", and does "damit" function as an adverb here since it comes last in the subordinate clause (I think it can also work as a conjunction)?

3: Can "das Leben der anderen" replace "das Leben eines anderen", and what are some differences between these 2 expressions?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: The three questions have no relation to each other except for stemming from the same quote. The question is too broad.

Comment: Also, you misidentified the verb in 1. It is *etwas verschwenden.* *Sich verschwenden* (which doesn’t really exist) would be ‘Verschwenden Sie **Sich** nicht damit …’

Answer (score 3):

1. There isn't a "sich" in the quote. *Sie* translates to *you*, the person addressed, while *sie* is *Ihre Zeit* from the previous clause.
2. *Damit* is an pronominal adverb answering the question word *womit?*, which asks for an agent or tool or, in case of time, an activity filling the time. It can't be left out in the second clause because the third clause explains in detail what the activity is. *Also* is a particle which marks the following as a conclusion or advice. The *also* the the beginning of the second clause can be left out.
3. "Das Leben der anderen leben" is an uncommon expression as it implies you are living the life of multiple other persons. Which is only possible when you assume "das Leben der anderen" is uniform – and thus, boring. Which hardly anyone would choose over living their own life.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1:

> Ihre Zeit ist begrenzt, also verschwenden Sie sie nicht damit, das Leben eines anderen zu leben.

Word-by-word translation (All words are translated in this context. Most words can mean other things in an other context)

- Ihre = Your (singular, Sie-Form)
- Zeit = time
- ist = is
- begrenzt = limited
- also = so
- verschwenden = waste
- Sie = you (singular, Sie-Form; meaning the same person as in the 1. word)
- sie = it (refers to *Zeit*)
- nicht = not
- damit = with
- das = the
- Leben = life
- eines = some
- anderen = other
- zu = to
- leben = live

All together, and rearranged:

> Your<sub>singular</sub> time is limited, so don't (you) waste it with living some other's life.

---

Version 2:

> Eure Zeit ist begrenzt. Vergeudet sie nicht damit, das Leben eines anderen zu leben.

- Eure = Your (plural, Du-Form)
- Zeit = time
- ist = is
- begrenzt = limited
- Vergeudet = waste
- sie = it (time)
- nicht = not
- damit = with
- das = the
- Leben = life
- eines = some
- anderen = other
- zu = to
- leben = live

Giving:

> Your<sub>plural</sub> time is limited, so don't (you) waste it with living some other's life.

---

1. **sich verschwenden**

   The verb »verschwenden« can not be used reflexive, and it is not used reflexive in your sentences. There is no »sich« in this sentences.
2. **also - damit**

   Those two words are not connected in a grammatical manner. They appear by accident in the same sentence, and have nothing to do with each other (in a grammatical sense).

   - **False friend alarm!** The German word »also« just means »so« in english

   > Ich habe eine Waffe, **also** benutze ich sie auch.
   >   I have a weapon, **so** I use it.

   The english word »also« is »auch« in German!

   > Ich habe **auch** einen Hund.
   >   I **also** have a dog.

   The word »damit« can be used as a subjunction or as pronominal adverb. Here it is used as adverb, and you can translate it as »with« or »with it«.
3. **»das Leben der anderen« vs. »das Leben eines anderen«**

   - »das Leben der anderen« is: »The life<sub>singular</sub> of the others<sub>plural</sub>«
   - »das Leben eines anderen« is: »The life<sub>singular</sub> of one other<sub>singular</sub>«

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no “sich” here. The second translation addresses the audience using second person plural. The imperative here is

   > Vergeudet!

   In second person singular it would have been

   > Vergeude!

   The first translation uses third person plural as a formal address (“Sie”). Here the imperative is

   > Vergeuden Sie!

   Hence the extra word. Whether we use “verschwenden” or “vergeuden” does not matter for this.
2. The construction here is “[die Zeit] mit *etwas* vergeuden”, and the *etwas* has to be replace by something. In English it might have been “waste the time with *living* [...]”, but in German gerund construction (or whatever it is, I am not a grammarian) is less natural, so wie use something else. Essentially we just put a “das” in the position in the position of the object and then explain that later on. So that would be (this is wrong):

   > * [...] vergeudet [die Zeit] nicht mit *dem*, das Leben eines anderen zu leben.

   However, the combination “mit dem” has to become “damit” here.

   > [...] vergeudet [die Zeit] nicht mit damit, das Leben eines anderen zu leben.
3. “Das Leben eines anderen” means “the life of an other (of someone else)”, so this is indefinite and singular. “Das Leben der anderen” would be “the life of the others” (definite article, plural), likely meaning of all others. That seems not to be intended, we are only talking about one life, and not of a particular person, but of someone non oneself.